# Keep a UITableView section from showing up as editing while the table is in edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, indentation, editmode

I've got 2 sections in a UITableView.  The tableview needs to stay in edit mode, but only the first section is editable.  Specifically, I want the second section to display as it would if the table were not in edit mode (tableviewcells are their original widths in stead of the left side being in line with the cells of the first (editable) section, which are aligned right, about 20% less wide than when in non-editing mode, and have the editing (-) icon to their left).  NOTE: the problem here is only with the appearance of the cells, not with the functional aspect of editable vs. non-editable cells.

Anyone know if this is possible within a single UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented [`tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:) in your `UITableViewDataSource`? That should give you the control you're looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for...I can't believe I missed it!!! Thanks :)